# Create a Table using LandXML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

I am using LandXML to create a the following table, but instead of Northing and Easting values, I would like to populate the Latitude and Longitude.

[Original Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLEs6.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu51o.png)

I know that the AlignPIs have the Attributes and nested attributes as shown below but having a hard time wrapping my head around accessing them and getting them into the actual table.
[AlignPIs Attribute Mapping][3]

[AlignPI Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLEs6.png)

[PI Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu51o.png)

And this is what I have so far for my code

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:lx="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:landUtils="http://www.autodesk.com/land/civil/vcedit"
 xmlns:lxml="urn:lx_utils">
 <!--Description:Tabulation of Alignment PI with Station, Latitude and Longitude.
This form is valid for LandXML 0.88, 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 data.-->
 <!--CreatedBy:Mark Hultgren -->
 <!--DateCreated:06/01/2018 -->
 <!--LastModifiedBy:Mark Hultgren -->
 <!--DateModified:06/01/2018 -->
 <!--OutputExtension:html -->
 <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />
 <!-- ==== JavaScript Includes ==== -->
 <xsl:include href="header.xsl" />
 <xsl:include href="UELS_Alignment_Layout.xsl" />
 <!--AlignmentPI Parameters-->
 <xsl:param name="PINumber" select="//lx:AlignPI/*/@pntRef" />
 <xsl:param name="PIStation" select="//lx:AlignPI/*/@Station" />
 <xsl:param name="PILatitude" select="//lx:AlignPI/*/@latitude" />
 <xsl:param name="PILongitude" select="//lx:AlignPI/*/@longitude" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="AlignPIs" test="//lx:AlignPI/*/@PI">
    <!--if there is diameterUnit, use it as pipe diameter dimension unit-->
    <xsl:value-of select="//lx:Units/*/@diameterUnit" />
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <!--otherwise, use linearUnit-->
    <xsl:value-of select="//lx:Units/*/@linearUnit" />
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:param>
  <!-- ============================= -->
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Alignment PI Station report with Latitude and Longitude<br/>  for <xsl:value-of select="//lx:Project/@name" /></title>
    <style type="text/css">
     div{
     width:10.5in;
     font-family:Verdana;
     }
     th{
     font-size:12pt;
     text-align:center;
     text-decoration:underline;
     }
     td{
     padding:0.02in 0.15in;
     text-align:right;
     }
     tr{
     font-size:10pt;
     }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div>
     <xsl:call-template name="AutoHeader">
      <xsl:with-param name="ReportTitle">Alignment PI Report</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="ReportDesc">
       <xsl:value-of select="//lx:Project/@name" />
      </xsl:with-param>
     </xsl:call-template>
     <br />
     <xsl:for-each select="//lx:Alignment/lx:AlignPIs">     
     <b>Alignment: <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></b>
     <br />Project Name [(Edit This)]
     <table bordercolor="black" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Station</th>
        <th>Latitude</th>
        <th>Longitude</th>
       </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="./lx:AlignPIs/lx:AlignPI">
        <tr>
         <xsl:variable name="PINumber" select="pntRef/@text()"
         <xsl:variable name="Station" select="AlignPI/@Station" />
         <xsl:variable name="PI" select="latitude" />
         <xsl:variable name="PI" select="longitude" />
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$PINumber" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$Station" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$latitude" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$longitude" />
         </td>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some problems with your XPath expressions and context nodes. 
You're starting out with a context node of AlignPIs:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//lx:Alignment/lx:AlignPIs">
```

In this context, "." refers to the lx:AlignPIs element that the XSLT processor is currently working on. In the next, inner for-each, you must write the following to select all `<AlignPi>` elements within the current context:

```
<xsl:for-each select="lx:AlignPI">
```

(`<xsl:for-each select="./lx:AlignPI">` is an equivalent statement)

Now your context node inside of the second for-each block is lx:AlignPI.

When you are defining your variables, you are trying to reference the latitude and longitude attributes of the PI child element.
Try the following expression for the latitudes and longitudes:

```
<xsl:variable name="latitude" select="lx:PI/@latitude" />
<xsl:variable name="longitude" select="lx:PI/@longitude" />
```

To elaborate a bit on this: As I mentioned, within the inner `<xsl:for-each ...>` your context node is now lx:AlignPI. The latitude and longitude attributes are not attached to lx:AlignPI, but to the PI child element. So in your XPath statement, you need to "navigate" to the lx:PI element first, and then get access to the attributes from there.

Comment: Thank you @Kai, 
This what I have in the parameters section now
[code] <xsl:param name="PILatitude" select="//lx:PI/@latitude" />
 <xsl:param name="PILongitude" select="//lx:PI/@longitude" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="//lx:Alignment/lx:AlignPIs">
    <xsl:for-each select="lx:AlignPI">
     <xsl:for-each select="lx:AlignPI/lx:PI">
     <xsl:variable name="latitude" select="lx:PI/@latitude" />
     <xsl:variable name="longitude" select="lx:PI/@longitude" />
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>[/code]